# How to configure IIS log destination programmatically via ServerManager API

Tags: c#, iis

I'm using `Microsoft.Web.Administration` library to manage IIS sites and app pools and it works great. However, I would need to be able to control how event logging is configured to ensure that certain events indeed generate ETW entries.

I'm talking about being able to change this specific setting via code (I'm showing the UI from IIS Manager here):

[image: IIS Manager]

What is the correct way to do this via `ServerManager` in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following C# code can set the `Log Event Destination` to `ETW event only` in IIS.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

internal static class Sample {

    private static void Main() {
        
        using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 
            Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
            
            ConfigurationSection sitesSection = config.GetSection("system.applicationHost/sites");
            
            ConfigurationElement siteDefaultsElement = sitesSection.GetChildElement("siteDefaults");
            
            ConfigurationElement logFileElement = siteDefaultsElement.GetChildElement("logFile");
            logFileElement["logTargetW3C"] = @"ETW";
            
            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```